# Combining results before grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, group-by

I want to work out the male/female split of my customer based on the person's title (Mr, Mrs, etc)

To do this I need to combine the result for the Miss/Mrs/Ms into a 'female' field.

The query below gets the totals per title but I think I need a sub query to return the combined female figure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Query:
SELECT c.Title, COUNT(*) as Count
FROM
   Customers c
GROUP BY Title
ORDER By [Count] DESC

Answer:
Mr  1903
Miss    864
Mrs 488
Ms  108
```

Comment: Female = `select COUNT(*) from Customers where Title <> 'Mr'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do it like this

```
SELECT 
  [Gender] = CASE [Title] WHEN 'Mr' THEN 'M' ELSE 'F' END, 
  COUNT(*) as Count
FROM
   Customers c
GROUP BY 
  CASE [Title] WHEN 'Mr' THEN 'M' ELSE 'F' END
ORDER By 
  [Count] DESC
```

Demo at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/05c74/4

Comment: Hi Gaby. This is the first answer that works satisfactorily. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use CASE to project the new groups for the Titles:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Title IN ('Mr') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Male,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Title IN ('Miss', 'Ms', 'Mrs') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Female
FROM
   Customers c;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN c.Title = 'Mr' THEN 'Male' 
             WHEN c.Title IN ('Mrs', 'Miss', 'Ms') THEN 'Female' 
             ELSE 'NA' 
        END) AS title, 
        COUNT(1) AS PeopleCount
FROM Customers c
GROUP BY (CASE WHEN c.Title = 'Mr' THEN 'Male' 
              WHEN c.Title IN ('Mrs', 'Miss', 'Ms') THEN 'Female' 
              ELSE 'NA' 
         END)
ORDER By PeopleCount DESC;
```

Comment: Hi Saharsh, that query creates three separate 'female' records

Comment: I wanted to acheive:Male: 332 Female: 284. Your query gave me Male 332
Female 178
Female 90
Female 16